# creating an array of indexes that has the size of the loop that fills the data

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

This is the method im having issues with
this is the code with isssues
this is code im having issues with

```
        static void FindDuplicates(int maxValue, int[]totalOfScores) {
            int finalWinner = 0;
            int i = 0;
            int[] WinnerIndex = new int [totalOfScores.Length];


            for (int g = 0; g < totalOfScores.Length; g++) {
                if (totalOfScores[g] == maxValue)
                    for (i = 0; i < WinnerIndex.Length; i++) {
                        WinnerIndex[i] = g;
                        finalWinner = WinnerIndex[i];
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\nThe Highest Scoring comp was comp Number {0} With a total score of {1}", finalWinner + 1, maxValue);
                    }

            }

        }
```

Comment: I just need to know: why are you unable to use LINQ? I can't think of any valid reason.

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex So you don't know how to solve it without LINQ?

Comment: Usually when I want to use an indeterminate number of items, I use a List, which also has a ToArray method if you really need an array once you constructed it. I find LINQ not only better to solve this kind of situations, though, but also more descriptive. You can read it and understand the intention behind it. And since it is part of any .NET framework, I really want to know where a restriction against LINQ would be coming from.

Comment: Just a note one the code: as far as I can see, maxIndex in FindMaxValue does not do anything and can be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is on the dynamic array size, do not use array, use List instead. Or use Array.Resize(). But if I understand your goal correctly, you are trying to list all competitors that have the highest score, in this example competitors 3 and 4 you don't really need array for the results at all. Instead do:

```
static void FindDuplicates(int maxValue, int[] totalOfScores){ 
    for (int i = 0; i < totalOfScores.Length; i++) {
        if (totalOfScores[i] == maxValue){
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nThe Highest Scoring comp was comp Number {0} With a total score of {1}", i+1, maxValue);
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, I would rename FindDuplicates as FindAllWinners (or then I have misunderstood your intentions).